# How to parse data from website that requires a login I.e. username and password In android app

Tags: android, parsing

In an android app. My college's website is www.academics.vit.ac.in > parent login.
now that requires a username and date of birth (13011995- Format) and captcha for login.and further it displays the details as marks , time table on navigation.It's a session based website and logs out automatically after some time of inactivity.so how do I parse information in an android app.

Comment: I am also searching for some help in the same issue. I would like to know if you got some help??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you cannot parse information in android application from such a website, until you have database access from the college or the website provides data in some format like JSON or XML. There are a lot of ways to fetch and parse JSON or XML that can be accesed using a http get or post request.

Comment: there exists a app already that does named VIT academics ...i  do not know how to parse authenticated data...

Comment: or take any other site that requires login and pass and captcha  and please tell me how to parse authenticated data ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480130/parsing-html-in-java-for-an-android-app